# R remove a row if it meets a condition or is a particular row number

Tags: r, dataframe

I have something like

```
Name   Data1   Data2
John   4       3
Jack   6       2
Jill   5       14
...    ...     ...
```

and want to remove any row where data2 is more than 10 as well as row 5. I can do that as

```
df = df[df$data2>10,]
df = df[-5,]
```

but is there a way to put these onto one line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry for before !
try this statement:

```
df = df[-c(which(df$data2>10),5),]
```

Comment: As it stands this isn't equivalent to J.Does version. I believe it should be `df = df[-c(which(df$data2<=10),5),]`.

Comment: Or `df[-c(which(!df$data2>10),5),]`.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to settle on an indexing scheme. Could be either logical or numeric.  If numeric then:

```
df[-c( which(df$data2>10) , 5), ]  # duplicates don't break numeric indexing
```

... if logical (negation) then:

```
df[ !(df$data2>10|(rownames(df)==5)),] # duplicates don't break logical indexing
```

Comment: Or you can mix and match: `df[df$data2>10,][-5,]`